# How to share Internet connection of VMWare guest with host in VMWare Player?

Tags: internet, vmware-player

I have a cheap 3G Internet stick with no driver support for my current operating system, yet that is currently my only way to get online. I had no trouble getting a connection with VMWare Player and XP as guest, but how do I share this connection with my host operating system (Windows 8)?

I tried NAT which according to VMWare doesn't allow the guest to work as a server and thus shouldn't be the proper option. I tried to bridge the connection and use ICS in the guest operating system, but that didn't work either. Can someone explain a step-by-step way to achieve that connection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Follow the instructions step by step since in some cases the order is important.

#### Setting up VMware Player

1. Right-click the Network Adapter icon and choose *Settings...*
2. Make sure the *Connected* value is checked in the *Device status* section.
3. Select the *Host-only: A private network shared with the host* value in the *Network connection* section and click *OK* to save the settings

---

#### Setting up Guest (Windows XP)

1. Open *Control Panel* and proceed to *Network and Internet Connections*
2. Here you should see two connections: the connection to the host and the connection to the Internet. They won't, most likely, have any precise titles, but you should be able to identify which one is which by connecting and disconnecting the 3G stick
3. Right-click the connection to the Internet, open *Properties*, *Advanced* tab and check the *Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection* value in the *Internet Connection Sharing* section. Then click *OK* to save the properties
4. Right-click the connection to the host, open *Properties*, select *Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)* in the *General* tab and open its *Properties*. Select the *Use the following IP address* value and fill in the following:

   ```
   IP address:           192.168.17.2
   Subnet mask:          255.255.255.0
   ```

   Leave all other fields blank and click *OK* twice to save the properties.
5. Open *Control Panel* once again, proceed to *Windows Firewall*, *Advanced* tab and uncheck the connection to the host in the *Network Connection Settings* section. Then click *OK* to save the settings

---

#### Setting up Host (Windows 8)

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> » then type *View network connections* and open it
2. Find the connection called *VMware Network Adapter VMnet1*, open its properties, select *Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)* in the *Networking* tab and open its *Properties*. Make sure the *Use the following IP address* value is selected and fill in the following:

   ```
   IP address:           192.168.17.1
   Subnet mask:          255.255.255.0
   Default gateway:      192.168.17.2
   Preferred DNS server: 192.168.17.2
   ```

   Leave the alternate DNS server field blank and click *OK* twice to save the properties.
3. Clear the *Default gateway* in the same menu before you start to use another Internet connection

The Internet in Windows 8 should now work.

Comment: How about if vmware guest is ubuntu?

Comment: Amazing. I can't believe this actually worked!

Answer (score 0):

**restoring** VMWare network setting to defaultfrom **Virtual Network Editor** Fixed my problem

see the more detailed answer with images at the below post
https://superuser.com/a/1130121/57836