# vmware workstation - cannot change network to bridged

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

i'm using vmware workstation 11. I can not bridge my network adapter.
When i view Virtual network editor, there is not any bridged vmnet. I have NAT vmnet8 and host-only vmnet1.
I added vmnet0 and changed Vmnet Information to Bridged and this error occured: Cannot change network to bridged: There are no un-bridged host network adapters.
Reinstallation of vmware didn't solve the problem.
Can you help me?
Regards,
Siavash

Comment: Look at the network editor. Does in the row `External connection` one of the vmnet has set `Auto-bridging`? If yes, click on it and chosse in `bridged to` one of your adapters. Every physical network card can be bridged only once.

Comment: Is your NIC working fine and has updated drivers?

Comment: Dear boboes, No, First one is "-"  and the second is NAT. there isn't any bridged vmnet.

Comment: Scorpion, my NIC is working in Host-only and NAT mode.

Comment: if u have kaspersky antivirus run vmware as Administrator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have uninstalled kaspersky antivirus and problem solved!

Answer (score 6):

In my situation in Windows 10 running VMware Workstation 11.1, after **restoring** network setting to **default**(image 2) from **Virtual Network Editor** everything gets back to normal and I could get my WiFi internet shared.

- My VM's network adapter setting is in **NAT mode** and no extra
  manual IP were configured for my VM and my Host
- kindly note that before restoring to default all VMs should be turned
  off as suggested by the button itself if it is not
- note that during resetting even **VMnet0** with Bridged type which was not present become available too. maybe i have stopped some VmWare services related to this and restoring to default fix the related services too

Image 1:

[image: VMWare Virtual Network Editor]

Image 2:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to uninstall the antivirus, simply go to your Physical network card properties, and uncheck the kaspersky anti-virus ndis 6 filter option.

Thats it....